# Noetherian local domain $A$ with a prime $P$ so that $\operatorname{ht}P+\dim A/P<\dim A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Is there a noetherian local domain $A$ with a prime $P$ so that $\operatorname{ht}P+\dim A/P<\dim A$?

This is a follow up question to: [Does codimension behave weirdly even in local rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545728/does-codimension-behave-weirdly-even-in-local-rings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is pointed out in Matsumura, CRT, page 31, for a noetherian local domain $A$ the equality $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak p+\dim A/\mathfrak p=\dim A$ holds for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ iff $A$ is catenary. So, we are looking for a noetherian local domain which is not catenary. There are no trivial examples, but you can find one at http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JE.